# Robots.txt - Magento not in root folder

Tags: robots.txt

I'm trying to update my robots.txt file for magento installed in a folder `public_html/shop/`.

I've updated my [robots.txt](http://www.ofarm.com.au/robots.txt) and .htaccess file based on solutions provided on below post:
[Google Ignore's Magento's robots.txt](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91727/google-ignores-magentos-robots-txt)

However from testing on Google Webmaster all files seem to open and none is getting blocked by the robots.txt file. By some hit and trail method I've reached a conclusion that it's not working because my Magento is installed in a folder rather than root. Below are examples of my testing:

- Fail: `Disallow: /app/` - Allowed (doesn't work)
- Pass: `Disallow: /shop/app/` - Blocked (works)

However for all Disallows I cannot prefix `/shop` as some disallows are within some folders. I know I can somehow use `*` or `/` and the robots.txt will work but not sure how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed Magento 1.x in the `shop` directory, you *can* use the robots.txt from [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/91728/243) which you already found and prefix all those entries with `/shop`.

i.e. `/app/` => `/shop/app/`

However, this message seems to indicate a different problem:

> Fail Disallow: /app/ - Allowed (doesn't work)

It seems like you have a different application installed at document root level or at least a directory `app` next to `shop` and did not block it. This has nothing to do with your Magento installation in `shop`.

If there's nothing, the message is a false alert and you don't need to worry about it.